# Powershell: regex on Get-EventLog output and find largest number

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to pull a particular number from the output of this command:

```
Get-EventLog "application" | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6006}
```

Sample output is:

```
Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
18297 May 15 18:49  Warning     Wlclntfy               2147489654 The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> took 60 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon).
11788 Jan 31 08:11  Warning     Wlclntfy               2147489654 The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> took 68 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon).
5794 Oct 16 09:41  Warning     Wlclntfy               2147489654 The winlogon notification subscriber <Sens> took 225 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logoff).
5596 Oct 11 08:03  Warning     Wlclntfy               2147489654 The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> took 69 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon).
2719 Aug 30 07:50  Warning     Wlclntfy               2147489654 The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> took 65 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon).
```

What I actually need to do is pull the number of seconds reported by the `<Profiles>` events, and pull out the largest one.  I've gotten as far as figuring out `(?<=<Profiles> took )(\d+)` will work to pull just the numbers I need, but I'm not sure how to proceed to actually extract them.  I've tried piping it to Select-String -pattern, but that just returns nothing at all.

Comment: you need to write a loop and keep comparing the numbers regex returns to find the largest one. AFAIK, a regex can not be return the largest number :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `$matches` builtin variable.  `$matches[0]` is the text that matched the regexp, and `$matches[1] .. $matches[n]` are the matched parenthetical expressions (if there were any).
Sadly I don't have any EventID=6006 on my machine so I'm doing this without testing, but this should select the last item from the sorted list of seconds:

```
Get-EventLog "application" | 
    Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6006} | 
    Where-Object { $_.Message -match "<Profiles> took (\d*) second" } |
    foreach { [int]$matches[1] } |
    sort |
    select -last 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value(s) without regex. Take a look at the ReplacementStrings property of the event. It contains an array that holds the replacement strings stored in the event entry.

```
PS> $event.ReplacementStrings
Profiles
71
Logon
```

Based on that you could use array indexing to get the values you're after.

```
Get-EventLog application | 
Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6006 -and $_.ReplacementStrings -eq 'Profiles'} | 
Foreach-Object { $_.ReplacementStrings[1] }
```